# Can the close review queue stop assuming that an edit to a duplicate is the last action I want to take?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, closing, reviewing

**Disclaimer:** This is about closing as **duplicates** only - not other types of closures.

---

When in the review queue for close votes, I sometimes find myself reviewing a question that has been voted for closure as a duplicate, where the title or body has some formatting & grammar issues that need fixing up.*

For example, there was [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/76267). From the [revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/161207/revisions), all I did was change the title from

> ### GTA4 (Steam) on Ubuntu

to

> ### Is it possible to run the Steam version of GTA 4 on Ubuntu?

I **still think this question is a duplicate** of [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/how-do-you-get-your-steam-games-to-run-on-ubuntu-through-wine-or-something-simil), however after the edit, the review queue auto jumped to the next item in the queue - i.e. not giving me a chance to close the question.

Granted, I can visit my Profile page, click on 'Activity', see the recent Edit action, click to navigate to the question, and finally click 'Close', but that's a lot of clicks I have to take.

I could also remember to middle-click the title when reviewing to go directly to the question and edit/close from there, but that kinda shirks the whole review-queue idea.

So, I request that the auto-redirect after reviewing duplicate close votes be removed, and instead we have to click <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> like the other review queues.

<sub>* Duplicate questions aren't eventually removed like the other close reasons. They're considered helpful in terms of providing different ways of phrasing the same question, as well as links back to the original question and answers. So I edit them under the pretense that it might be the first thing visitors see. In other words, I prefer a patched up window to a broken one.</sub>

Comment: **Related**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169988/let-me-edit-a-post-in-the-close-review-then-vote-to-close-it **and** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212862/warn-about-editing-questions-in-the-close-votes-review-queue, especially take a look at Shog9's answer in the second link, it covers this pretty well.

Comment: @3ventic - Shog's answer makes the assumption that every close reason is treated the same (close->delete), which is simply not the case here. We don't delete duplicates, thus 'edit & close' **is** a viable path.

Comment: But the edit button's description holds true: "improve so that it does not need to be closed." If you edit for another reason, it's easy enough to open the question itself.

Comment: @3ventic - Of the functionality that I'm asking to be changed, a tooltip is probably the easiest of the lot.

Comment: Worth noting that if you're leaving duplicates around as sign-posts, *changing the wording* is probably counterproductive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Close Vote queue exists for one specific purpose: To determine whether or not a question should be closed.

Editing a minor grammar or formatting issue is *not* a Close Vote review action. Open the question, do the edit outside the review queue. In the queue, you should only perform *queue-relevant* actions. An edit that doesn't change anything about whether or not the question should be closed is *not* such a queue-relevant action.

Comment: Closing is not the sole purpose of *any* review queue, and I'm honestly kinda shocked you think that. The purpose of the review queues is to a) determine good from bad, b) edit bad into good, and finally c) If bad cannot be salvaged, to close/delete. Now I'm talking about **duplicates** specifically, so I'll say again: closure != deletion in this case, therefore editing grammar etc = good. What I'm asking is that **if** a question is in the review queue for 'duplicate', let us edit it without the assumed agreement that edit=leave open. That's all. All other close actions remain the same.

Comment: I did not say "closing was the purpose of that queue", did I now? I said the **close votes** review queue is about determining **whether or not a question should be closed**. An edit that changes nothing about that is *irrelevant* there - it does not actually *review* the item in *what the queue is about*. You also have not fully clarified in your question that you want this *only* for possible duplicates. (Which [might get their own queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue/226183#comment739593_226092) anyway.)

Comment: I must've read that first part wrong, I apologise. As for clarity of *dupes* in my question however... well it's right there in the title. And the first sentence. And the example I give is a question VTC'd as dupe. I even reaffirm that I think it's a dupe, and then go on to talk about closing as dupe :P. Nevermind, I've now added a disclaimer. Hopefully that'll clear things up

Comment: An Edit for clarification is part of the low quality and first post queue, I also can then go on to downvote, flag, leave a comment without ever leaving the queue, before clicking 'I'm Done'. That's all I'm asking for here. The ability to edit a dupe and **then** go on to close. If you ask me, that's exactly why they're in the queue to begin with. To be **reviewed**.

Comment: @Robotnik That's what we have *quality* review queues for, though. These are very distinct concepts with very distinct goals. Mind you, I think a separate duplicate queue would be well-served with such a feature, but the *close vote* queue is about *figuring out if a question should be closed, and fixing it if not*, not about the general quality of the post.

Comment: Our distinct goals (as a site) is good, readable content that's easy to find. Every review queue works toward those goals. If and when we get a duplicate queue that allows us to edit & close, great. Until such time however, the close queue is all we've got. However, without the ability to edit AND close as dupe from the one place, you're forcing people to do one or the other- either edit and leave open, or close and leave as bad content. Forcing people to navigate away to perform both is bad design and doesn't allow us to accomplish both goals